# How to customize the spring boot default properties of connection pool

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, connection-pooling

I am using Spring boot + MySQL + Data JPA.
When I started my spring boot app, its taking initial pool size as 10.

I have tried to customize it using following property:

```
spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=20
```

But its not working. How to fix this ?

Comment: The default pool is Hikari not dbcp2...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't configure your Connection Pool, Spring Boot will pick `HikariCP` at default. The connection pool for `HikariCP` can be configured as following:

`spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5`